# nested and dynamically created ng-model into ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know there is a lot of question about this problem but i couldn't resolve my problem.

the final outcome of my project is to create a xml file.

For this i need to ask the user to chose a root node and depending on his choice i send a request to my db to retrieve possible children of this root node. Then he chose the child he wants and i sent another request to retrieve possible children for this node and so on until i reach a leaf.

So i need to make drop down list appears dynamically. But to be able to create the xml i need to save every choice he made so i need to keep the selected node in separate ng-model.

Based on other questions and and their answers i tried this :

html:

```
    <select ng-model='selectedstandard' ng-options='item for item in standard' ng-change="getTypes()">
        <option value="">select standard</option>
    </select>

    <select ng-model='selectedstandard[$index]' ng-options='item for item in standard' ng-change="getTypes()" ng-repeat="node in nodes">
        <option value="">select standard</option>
    </select>
```

maincontroller.js :

```
$scope.nodes=[];
$scope.getTypes = function(){
  $scope.types = $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost:8080/hello/types',
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'standard' : $scope.selectedstandard}
     }).success(function (data) 
     {
         $scope.types=data;
         var i=0;
         var simpleTypesTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.types));
         for(var ty in $scope.types){
         var valuetab=($scope.types[ty]).split(":");
         simpleTypesTemp[ty]= valuetab[0]+":...:"+valuetab[(valuetab.length)-1];
     }
 });
 if($index){
    $scope.nodes.push($scope.selectedstandard[$index]);
 }
 else{
    $scope.nodes.push($scope.selectedstandard);
  }
  $scope.getNameSpace();
}
```

But i get an error telling me $index isn't defined.

I guess the two ng-model named selectedstandard and selectedstandard[$index] is not a very good idea but i need to initialize the loop a way or another.

Comment: where does this $index come from? Did you mistaken $index from ng-repeat with it?

Comment: honestly i don't really know because i tried to adapt some code i saw in another question. But i guess it's the $index from ng-repeat.

Comment: Then you can't use it here, although is $scope.selectedstandard setup after you use it in headers: {} ?

Comment: It is set before and the http request doesn't affect it

Comment: I know that http doesn't affect it as it's just using it to make a request but scope.getTypes makes the http request and then set the "selectedstandard" so at this point I want to ask what this logic [if/else] should do, what $index you are checking and why?

Comment: the if/else logic is supposed to fill the nodes Array so the ng repeat is updated but it should only push the latest selectedstandard. That's the index i'm trying to check.

Comment: I see, so in that case it should be:
lastIndex = angular.isArray($scope.selectedstandard.length) ? $scope.selectedstandard.length -1 : null;
if(lastindex >== 0){
    $scope.nodes.push($scope.selectedstandard[lastIndex]);
 }

Comment: i'm not sure that i understand you well. Should it be ng-model=selectedstandard? without the $index but with the code you wrote in the controller?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or plunker with your example as I'm slowly getting lost ;)

Comment: Hum here is it but since my db is hosted locally it won't be very usefull. http://plnkr.co/edit/Hsaq7X3iqHtXIVIx6ZkE?p=preview